# How to extract web page HTML data into XML with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, extract

I have a static HTML page with a form. I want to extract data from text box or use the data in XML into textbox with the help of javascript.

Will appreciate any help or pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are tutorials [1](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/More-on-JavaScript-and-XML/), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Parsing_and_serializing_XML) .

```
(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlNode) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a DOM. Look up examples on w3schools.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any tutorials how to make XML with javascript and DOM?

Answer (score 0):

you can use usefull jquery function [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) and serialize()

edit:to write xml with javascript [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/XMLWriter.aspx]